# Folium: Circle Marker from GeoJson

Tags: python, geometry, geojson, marker, folium

I would like to represent points from geojson file on a map as circle markers, not as simple markers, which are shown by default.

The following command would add simple markers:

```
folium.GeoJson(geojson_file).add_to(map)
```

How should I change them to circle markers. I don't want to do a for loop for each point as it is takes a very long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this (using example from Leaflet API)
More on that topic here http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson

```
   function style (feature, latlng) {
     return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                    radius: 8,
                    fillColor: "#ff7800",
                    color: "#000",
                    weight: 1,
                    opacity: 1,
                    fillOpacity: 0.8
                });
   };

   geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojson_file,{
      pointToLayer: style  
  }).addTo(map);
```